# Is TensorFlow only limited to neural networks?

Tags: tensorflow

Is the TensorFlow designed only for implementing neural networks? Can it be used as a general machine learning library -- for implementing all sorts of supervised as well as unsupervised techniques (naive baysian, decision trees, k-means, SVM to name a few) ? Whatever TensorFlow literature I am coming across is generally talking about neural networks. Probably graph based architecture of TensorFlow makes it suitable candidate for neural nets. But can it be also used as a general Machine Learning framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tensorflow does include additional machine learning algorithms such as:

```
K-means clustering
Random Forests
Support Vector Machines
Gaussian Mixture Model clustering
Linear/logistic regression
```

The above list is taken from [here](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/08/06/tensorflow-not-just-deep-learning/), so you can read this link for more details.

Comment: Does that mean TF can run these models on GPU's and scale to large datasets?

Comment: Tensor-flow is not taking advantage of GPU in shallow ml algorithms like above.

Comment: It seems TF Estimators is deprecated now. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator